# How to center pagination?

Tags: html, css, css-position

You can view the page I'm working on here:  http://stats.escalatehosting.com/whois.php

The problem I'm having is that I just can't figure out what CSS needs to be changed to center the page numbers located at the top and bottom of the page.  I've tried changing everything I can think of but it always ends up off-center when you start clicking to pages with larger numbers...

I'm not really sure what needs to be changed, if anyone has any suggestions, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *I've tried changing everything I can think* - Can you share those?

Comment: Sure, I've changed `#ct1_pager_container, #ct2_pager_container` to `float:center;`, added in `text-align:center;` added in `margin:auto;` and several other things but they all cause it to still be slightly off-center and dropped down to overlap the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you commented, `center` is not a valid value for `float` property, either you can use `left`, `right` or `none` which is default.

On `creative2tables` line 167 change your CSS as provided below..

```
#ct1_pager_container, #ct2_pager_container {
   margin-bottom: 15px;
   clear: right; /* Not sure if required */
   width: 300px;
}
```

And in the same stylesheet on line 174 change the below as

```
#ct1_pager, #ct2_pager {
   clear: both;
   list-style: none;
}
```

---

I've changed the above properties to center your pagination, please do check if you are using these id's for any other element as well.

Comment: That almost fixed it 100%, but try clicking to the last page and then going down a few - like to page 1346.  It seems to be messing up around that area...

Comment: @user2970202 looks good to me, if you want, just provide some extra width to your container element, so instead of `width: 300px;` you can try `width: 400px;`

Comment: Actually, I just fixed that real quick - it was just an issue with the width.

Comment: @user2970202 That's what I told you to do :)

Comment: Lol I didn't see your response until I'd already posted that :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to update below Class.

```
#ct1_pager_container, #ct2_pager_container{
    width:100%;
}
#ct1_pager, #ct2_pager{
    float:none;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Update only given element. don't update whole CSS. keep everything else as it is.